# Finding Importance Value from Spark's Decision Tree using MLlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, decision-tree, apache-spark-mllib

We are running Spark 1.0 or 1.1 for Decision Tree using MLlib.

When I run the sample SCALA code with sample data, it worked with no error, but I could not find the feature importance from the result.

Anybody has such an information on how to get the values?

Comment: Please post what you tried and your results. We're not telepathic.

Answer (score 3):

In Spark 2+ you can do the following:

```
val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureArray)
val decisionTreeModel = decisionTree.fit(trainingDataset)
val featureImportances = decisionTreeModel.featureImportances // Sparse or Dense Vector

featureArray.zip(featureImportances.toArray).sortBy(_._2).reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

When you train DecisionTreeModel at the end you have this class

```
class DecisionTreeModel(val topNode: Node, val algo: Algo) {
   ...
}
```

You can start traversing nodes from top, and you can get all you need from it (predict + InformationGainStats)

```
class Node (
    val id: Int,
    val predict: Double,
    val isLeaf: Boolean,
    val split: Option[Split],
    var leftNode: Option[Node],
    var rightNode: Option[Node],
    val stats: Option[InformationGainStats])
```